# Generating JWT in Laravel Can Not Validate User

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I'm trying to setup JWT using Laravel.

I'm basically following the info form the jwt package and another page:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth
https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

I've got a few differences, mainly user model is called Human, but for the most part I'm following the examples above

The issue is that I can't validate a user.  Whenever I hit the route with a post request I get the 401 Error. So I did some investigating in the php artisan tinker console. If I select the first user in my database check their password hash it's fine, this works:

```
$human = App\Human::first();
Hash::check('12345', $human['password']); // true
```

But if I try to generate a JWT, it fails.

```
JWTAuth::attempt(['email' => $human['email'], 'password' => '12345']); // false
```

I'm not sure where to go from here to debug this.

**UPDATE:**
The key to this is that my 'user' table is actually called 'humans'.  I had a user table hanging around in my database and as soon I removed it I got an error that the user table doesn't exist.

I did change this this line in my jwt config:

```
'user' => 'App\Human',
```

To reflect that my 'user' model is called Human, and I went into the laravel auth.php and set my model there also.  Still when I call the JWTAuth attempt method it tries to access the 'users' table and not the 'humans' table where the passwords are actually stored.

Obviously I could change the table name but that makes another part of the application ugly. So I guess what I need is a way to configure jwt-auth to look at a different table.

Comment: have you find a working solution?

Comment: We have moved our 'users' back to the 'App/User' model.  I'd prefer to use a table called 'humans' and use a model called 'App\Human', but I can't figure out how to configure the JWT package to do this yet.

Comment: did u fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It may be ok when hashing the password, try this

```
JWTAuth::attempt(['email' => $human['email'], 'password' => bcrypt('12345')]);
```

Comment: All the example send the password to the attempt method unencrypted.  I added an update with more info.